# Create Unique constraint for 'true' only in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a class for tracking attachments to a Record. Each Record can have multiple RecordAttachments, but there is a requirement that there can only be one RecordAttachment per-Record that is marked as `IsPrimary`.

```
public class RecordAttachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

    public Record Record { get; set; }
}
```

I can't just use `.HasIndex(e => new { e.RecordId, e.IsPrimary }).IsUnique(true)` because there can be multiple `false` values per Record.

Basically I need a unique constraint on `RecordId` and `IsPrimary == true`, although this didn't work:

`entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.RecordId, IsPrimary = (e.IsPrimary == true) }).IsUnique(true)`

Edit:
Looking at answers like this: [Unique Constraint for Bit Column Allowing Only 1 True (1) Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141834/unique-constraint-for-bit-column-allowing-only-1-true-1-value) it appears this would be possible creating the constraint directly with SQL, but then it wouldn't be reflected in my Model.

Comment: It sounds like `Record` should have one primary `RecordAttachment` and many non-primary `RecordAttachment`s instead of having the `IsPrimary` column.  So basically a one-to-one relationship and then a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Another alternative would be to replace `IsPrimary` with an integer column where 1 would represent primary and you'd just set all the other's to unique values.

Comment: @juharr That would be an option if this isn't possible, add a `PrimaryAttachmentId` to `Record` and treat it separately.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can specify index filter using the [`HasFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalindexbuilderextensions.hasfilter?view=efcore-2.0) fluent API.

Unfortunately it's not database agnostic, so you have to use the target database SQL syntax and actual table column names.

For Sql Server it would be something like this:

```
.HasIndex(e => new { e.RecordId, e.IsPrimary })
.IsUnique()
.HasFilter("[IsPrimary] = 1");
```

or

```cs
    .HasIndex(e => new { e.RecordId, e.IsPrimary })
    .IsUnique()
    .HasFilter($"[{nameof(RecordAttachment.IsPrimary)}] = 1");
```

For more information, see [Relational Database Modeling - Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/indexes) documentation topic.

Comment: Excellent. My only gripe is using a string prevents it from changing automatically if the property is renamed, but oh well.

Comment: @Valuator For that you could use `nameof`.

Comment: Example using nameof: .HasIndex(e => new { e.RecordId, e.IsPrimary }).IsUnique().HasFilter($"[{nameof(RecordAttachment.IsPrimary)}] = 1");

Comment: I have a problem, when i am using this. I am also not allowed to insert an entry with isPrimary = false. Also throws duplicateEntry exception.

Comment: @liqSTAR Make sure you have created and applied migration including the above. i.e. the database and mode are in sync. also are you using SqlServer or different database?

Comment: Hey @ivan stoev found out that it is a mariadb bug reported in 2018.mariadb is ignoring conditional index or partial ones.

Comment: For everyone who needs the mentioned bug report:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15140