# Circular Dependency error when saving entity with a conditional unique constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This is a followup to what I did here: [Create Unique constraint for 'true' only in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069427/create-unique-constraint-for-true-only-in-ef-core)

I have a table with a unique constraint on two columns, `RecordId` and `IsPrimary`. There can only be one `true` value per `RecordId` in the `RecordAttachment` table. The migration created this index on the table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_RecordAttachment_RecordId_IsPrimary] 
ON [RecordAttachment] ([RecordId], [IsPrimary]) 
WHERE [IsPrimary] = 1;
```

In order to handle this on the server, I wrote my repository method to update the existing Primary Attachment when updating another `RecordAttachment` set as `IsPrimary`:

```
public async override Task<RecordAttachment> UpdateAsync(RecordAttachment item)
{
    if (item.IsPrimary)
    {
        RecordAttachment oldPrimaryAttachment = await _context.RecordAttachment
            .Where(ra => ra.RecordId == item.RecordId && ra.IsPrimary && ra.RecordAttachmentId != item.RecordAttachmentId)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (oldPrimaryAttachment != null)
        {
            oldPrimaryAttachment.IsPrimary = false;
            _context.RecordAttachment.Update(oldPrimaryAttachment);
        }
    }

    _context.RecordAttachment.Update(item);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return item;
}
```

However, now when I update an `Attachment` and set it as `Primary` when there is already another `Attachment` for the current record set as `Primary` - i.e. my update method has to update another attachment and set its `IsPrimary` field to `false` to accomodate the new `IsPrimary` attachment - I get this exception when saving the changes to the database:

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'Index: RecordAttachment.RecordId, RecordAttachment.IsPrimary Unique, Index: RecordAttachment.RecordId, RecordAttachment.IsPrimary Unique'.

Though, I don't know what the circular dependency is exactly. Inspecting the entities to be saved there are only 2 `RecordAttachment` entities and nothing else: 1 with `IsPrimary` set to `false` (previously `true`), and another with `IsPrimary` set to `true` (previously `false`), and both with the same `RecordId`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is EF Core internal processing bug due to the lack of real unique index filter expression definition. I don't see other workaround than intermediate `SaveChanges` after `oldPrimaryAttachment.IsPrimary = false;` line (btw, you don't need `_context.RecordAttachment.Update(oldPrimaryAttachment);`)

Comment: @IvanStoev that is working now. You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) stated in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105715/circular-dependency-error-when-saving-entity-with-a-conditional-unique-constrain#comment87230119_50105715), the solution would be to call `SaveChanges` right after you change the desired property. Something like this:

```cs
public async Task UpdateMyComplexUniqueIndexAsync(MyRequestDto input)
{
    var itemsWithUniqueIndex = await Repository
        .Where(it => ...)
        .ToListAsync();

    itemsWithUniqueIndex.ForEach(async it =>
    {
        it.MyProperty = string.Empty; // Change to desired value
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
}
```

---

**OBS:** The solution below is a workaround, it's not pretty and is far from good, but worked.

In my case, I was using the [ABP Framework](https://abp.io/), and even after using the proposed solution that didn't work.

I was making a drag-and-drop feature to change the `order` of a given list of elements, but this `order` was being used as a key to an index in my table, so I had to make this:

```cs
public async Task UpdateMyComplexUniqueIndexAsync(MyRequestDto input)
{
    var itemsWithUniqueIndex = await Repository
        .Where(it => ...)
        .ToListAsync();

    itemsWithUniqueIndex.ForEach(it => it.Order += 9999);

    itemsWithUniqueIndex.ForEach(async it =>
    {
        it.Order = CalculateNewOrder(input);
        await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
}
```

Basically, I changed all of the orders to a number that I knew not would be reached and then changed the order to the number that I actually wanted.

---

References:

- [Circular Dependency error when saving entity with a conditional unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105715/circular-dependency-error-when-saving-entity-with-a-conditional-unique-constrain#comment87230119_50105715)
- https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11888
- [Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60588549/unable-to-save-changes-because-a-circular-dependency-was-detected-in-the-data-to)