# Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add both a `ApplicationUser` and `Person` entity to my Context

My `ApplicationUser` class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public int? PersonID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public ICollection<UserSource> UserSources { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>> Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserToken<Guid>> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

My `Person` class

```
public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public int HeightInches { get; set; }

    public int WeightPounds { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string BatHand { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string ThrowHand { get; set; }

    public DimDate BirthDate { get; set; }

    public DimDate DeathDate { get; set; }

    public DimDate DebutDate { get; set; }
    public DimDate FinalDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("LeagueOwner")]
    public ICollection<League> LeaguesOwned { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Tuple.Create(this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.FullName).GetHashCode();
}
```

I am trying to create both of these entities, and then tie them together in the `RegisterUser` method of my `UserService`

```
Public Class UserService : IUserService
{
    private MyDbContext context;
    private ILogger logger;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public async Task<ApplicationUser> RegisterUser(RegistrationModel registrationModel)
    {
        // Create the User first
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = registrationModel.UserName,
            Email = registrationModel.Email
        };

        // Create the User with a password
        var result = await this.userManager.CreateAsync(user, registrationModel.Password);

        // Make sure the user is successfully created
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            try
            {
                this.logger.LogInformation($"User {user.UserName} successfully created and added to the database");

                // create a person for the User (this is causing me to have a headache...)
                // I originally had this is separate methods... moving into one so I can make more sense
                var fullName = (registrationModel.FirstName == registrationModel.LastName) ? registrationModel.FirstName : registrationModel.FirstName + " " + registrationModel.LastName;
                var newPerson = new Person
                {
                    FirstName = registrationModel.FirstName,
                    LastName = registrationModel.LastName,
                    FullName = fullName
                };

                // Add the person to the DB
                await this.context.People.AddAsync(newPerson);

                // Add the User to the Person and vice versa
                user.Person = newPerson;
                newPerson.User = user;

                // Save the changes
                await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
                this.logger.LogInformation($"Person for {user.NormalizedUserName} created");

                // Add source to the user
                var userSource = new UserSource
                {
                    MySource = registrationModel.WhereDidYouHear,
                    User = user
                };

                await this.context.UserSources.AddAsync(userSource);
                this.logger.LogInformation($"Source added to UserSources for {user.NormalizedUserName}");

                return user;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(error.Description);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

However, when this method executes, I am getting the following error in my log:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'Person [Added] <- Person { 'PersonID' } ApplicationUser [Added] <- User { 'UserID' } Person [Added]'

As far as I'm aware, I *think* I have the relationship set up correctly between `ApplicationUser` and `Person`, so I'm not sure why it's not allowing me to attach `Person` to `ApplicationUser` and vice versa.

I will include the `RegistrationModel` for reference, as data in this is used in the `RegisterUser` Method:

```
public class RegistrationModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,255}$")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Where did you hear about us?")]
    public string WhereDidYouHear { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: if your `Person` has a foreign key onto your `ApplicationUser`, and your `ApplicationUser` has a foreign key onto your `Person` how would one ever get created, when they're both dependent on the other to get created to have an ID to write as the foreign key? when the foreign key entity has not yet been created?

Comment: ...that's a very good question. So I should only point to one from the other and not vice versa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity framework Code First One-to-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376450/entity-framework-code-first-one-to-one-relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by deleting `PersonID` property in my `AspNetUser` class, and based my new setup from [This Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Here is my adjusted `AspNetUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public ICollection<UserSource> UserSources { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public ICollection<League> LeaguesOwned { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>> Claims { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>> Logins { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserToken<Guid>> Tokens { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

My `Person` class didn't change, so I made adjusted the `RegisterUser` method in my `UserService` to look as such:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private StatPeekContext context;
    private ILogger logger;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    /// <summary>
    /// This will register a new user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registrationModel"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<ApplicationUser> RegisterUser(RegistrationModel registrationModel)
    {
        // Create the User first
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = registrationModel.UserName,
            Email = registrationModel.Email
        };

        // Create the User with a password
        var result = await this.userManager.CreateAsync(user, registrationModel.Password);

        // Make sure the user is successfully created
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            try
            {
                this.logger.LogInformation($"User {user.UserName} successfully created and added to the database");

                var fullName = (registrationModel.FirstName == registrationModel.LastName) ? registrationModel.FirstName : registrationModel.FirstName + " " + registrationModel.LastName;
                var newPerson = new Person
                {
                    FirstName = registrationModel.FirstName,
                    LastName = registrationModel.LastName,
                    FullName = fullName,
                    UserID = user.Id
                };

                // Add the person to the DB
                await this.context.People.AddAsync(newPerson);

                this.logger.LogInformation($"Person for {user.NormalizedUserName} created");

                // Add source to the user
                var userSource = new UserSource
                {
                    MySource = registrationModel.WhereDidYouHear,
                    UserID = user.Id
                };

                await this.context.UserSources.AddAsync(userSource);
                await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
                this.logger.LogInformation($"Source added to UserSources for {user.NormalizedUserName}");

                return user;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(error.Description);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This looks like it solved it.