# EF Core Migration Constraint with condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following class:

```
public class VerizonRequest
{
    public VerizonRequest()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }

    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ResultDate { get; set; }
    public VerizonRequestStatus Status { get; set; } = VerizonRequestStatus.Pending;
    public VerizonRequestType RequestType { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

and Map class:

```
public class VerizonRequestMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<VerizonRequest>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VerizonRequest> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(VerizonRequest));
        builder.HasKey(d => d.RequestId);

        builder.HasOne(d => d.Device)
            .WithMany(d => d.VerizonRequests)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DeviceId);
    }
}
```

I want to create a constraint, which will unable to add one more record for the same DeviceId, if already have a record with the same DeviceId and Status = 'Pending'

So, it should be like:

```
builder.HasIndex(d => new { d.DeviceId, d.Status });
```

but only if Status = 'Pending' (pairs with DeviceId + Status can be more than one for Status != 'Pending', but for 'Pending' only one)

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you expect if the constraint isn't respected?

Comment: I suppose you need a filtered index. Is this SQL Server?

Comment: @DavidG yes, it's SQL Server

Comment: @vernou control on EF level to reject for adding new request if another active request already exists

Comment: So perhaps `builder.HasIndex(d => new { d.DeviceId, d.Status }).HasFilter("[Status] = 1");` (replace 1 with the pending value) will work?

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069427/create-unique-constraint-for-true-only-in-ef-core

Comment: Thanks for letting me add the answer.... sigh

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @DavidG, `HasFilter` helps me:

```
builder.HasIndex(d => new { d.DeviceId, d.Status }).HasFilter("[Status] = 1");
```