# In EF Core can I create a unique constraint on two columns where one column is a conditional boolean value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, unique-constraint

I'd like to create a unique condition on a row where only one can exist. One column would be a specific string and the other column would be a boolean of true

Ex. 2 columns

1. TransferGroup(string) = '123ABC'
2. IsStripeFeeRemoved(boolean) = true

So if a new row is inserted and TransferGroup is '123ABC' and IsStripeFeeRemoved is true then I get a
DbUpdateConcurrencyException or some other type of exception I can catch and correct before saving.
If IsStripeFeeRemoved is false then it will save ok.

How would I do this?

I tried this below but this is syntactically incorrect

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>()
  .HasIndex(p => new { p.TransferGroup, p.IsStripeFeeRemoved == true })
  .IsUnique();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Unique constraint for 'true' only in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069427/create-unique-constraint-for-true-only-in-ef-core)

Comment: So does that mean that if I say .HasFilter("[IsStripeFeeRemoved] = 1"); I can insert many rows where the value is false, but only 1 where the value is true? And if so, do you know what type of exception this will throw?

Comment: @user1186050 (1) That's exactly what it means (2) Not sure hundred percent (you can check that out), but I would expect the same exception you get for "regular" (non filtered) duplicate unique index value.